# Why dynamically allocated memory requires typecasting?

Tags: c++, c, malloc

In C address returned by malloc() typecasts implicitly and in C++ I need to typecast explicitly. But I'm using an integer pointer which will point out to next address according to the pointer arithmetic, then why do I need to typecast memory address?

I'm actually using 'new' keyword but I need to clear my thought on this.

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages. Unless you want to take a class learning C++, then I suggest [a couple of the books listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++. (there is low level stuff where you may need to but stick with `new` until then (and then don't even use `new` and use RAII containers like `vector` and smart pointers))

Comment: You don't need to typecast for either. And for C++  if you're using `new` properly (which, in modern C++ means you're not using it regardless), it normally shouldn't require type-casting. Your question would be well-served to include a realistic example where you feel typecasting is required in your C++. Odds are, neither casting nor dynamic manual management is needed at all.

Comment: can you show an example where you think you need a cast?

Comment: dynamically allocating memory is as simple as `std::vector<int> x;`, no need for `new` or casting ;)

Comment: @user463035818 Something like this I presume? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47ce070800ee19cf

Comment: [link] (http://https://ideone.com/0hRWv9)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat didnt say that I cannot imagine a situation where you would need a cast, but wanted to know what the question is about

Comment: And please read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (and note that it's for C only).

Comment: don't use malloc. Don't use `new`. Don't use manual memory management. Use containers and smart pointers.

Comment: *"Don't use `new`."* Except when writing a custom container, which for some reason can't be implemented properly using standard containers and smart pointers. Even then you should be very careful.

Answer (score 9):

> But I'm using an integer pointer which will point out to next address according to the pointer arithmetic

Yes it will, but it's not revelant here.

`malloc` returns a `void *`.

In C, a pointer to `void` can be *implicitly* converted to a pointer to any other type.

In C++, there is no such implicit conversion (presumably to make the language a bit more safe to use).

It's as simple as that.